# Data.STM.LinkedList implementation

Tags: haskell, doubly-linked-list

I'm looking at Data.STM.LinkedList implementation for a high performance linked list. Looking at the documentation, the length function run in O(n) - why is that ? Was there any real issue to implement it in O(1) ?

Here is the source code
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-linkedlist-0.1.0.0/docs/src/Data-STM-LinkedList-Internal.html#length

Is it possible implement it in O(1) ? i'm new to Haskell so I'm not sure if holding some metadata about the list is problematic.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you maybe expand this question with a little research? Can you post the relevant code, or link to it? Can you think of a O(1) implementation? I feel like this would make your question more interesting, both to read, and to answer.

Comment: It's not that simple to achieve that efficiently. One would need to add a pointer to each node in a list, pointing to the current size variable. Otherwise, each insertion/deletion would require two arguments (the list and the node) and that would allow a user to attempt to remove a node from the wrong list, potentially breaking the "size variable" invariant. Checking against that would require O(N) insertion/deletion, AFAICS.

Comment: So basically you are saying that there is no elegant way to implement that in Haskell ?

Comment: It looks like there is no fully safe and efficient way to implement it, in any language. This is not Haskell-specific. If you are OK with adding preconditions on the operations (e.g. you must never remove a node from a list unless it is indeed a node inside that list) and accept that violating that precondition will produce a wrong size, then you can implement it as a thin wrapper to the library.

Comment: But c++  stl implement it in o(1). So you test a flag on each deletion  to ensure consistency. Looks to me like a price worth paying.

Comment: @Gil Shafriri - Yes, in C++ it is O(1), but this does NOT include any cost related to mutual exclusion. _C++ philosophy:_ you don't pay for what you don't use. C++ STL code is written assuming a single threaded application, unlike STM stuff. The only way to get O(1) is to maintain a counter at _list_ level, hence a greater risk of failing a normally innocent `insertBetween` transaction. Note this [paper about Haskell STM implementation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3293883.3295711), normally behind a paywall, is now freely accessible courtesy of the coronavirus, I mean, of the ACM.

Comment: Thanks! So what are my options in Haskell to have a double linked list with a performance similar to c++ stl ,namely O(1) for the length function  ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the C++ docs for the container you want? My guess is that C++ is OK with violating the invariant if the user violates the preconditions. E.g. You can write `list.remove(node)` when `node` comes from _another_ `list`, and that will trigger undefined behavior. If you are OK with that, you can implement a thin wrapper over the current Haskell implementation, and be careful to properly call the deletion routines, with the same list the node occurs in.

Comment: For instance, try calling `std::list.erase` with an iterator coming from a different list object. I expect that will mess up the size counter and/or other invariants.

Comment: @chi instead of including in each node a pointer to the current size variable directly, make it point to the `List (nodes, size)` itself instead, no? then `remove node list` checks that node indeed points to that list, and only then removes the node by surgical relinking of its neighbors, otherwise does nothing. what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: @WillNess Sure, that works, but requires an additional pointer in each node, decreasing the memory efficiency. The mentioned STM implementation only requires 3 pointers per node: data/prev/next. I was working on the assumption we can't alter that.

Comment: Thanks you guys! So maybe  Data.STM.LinkedList  is not for me. I don't need  mutual exclusion.and just like something like stl with no protection. Do I have to write it myself or is there anything ready I can use ?

Comment: @chi - I think you can have a safe implementation without much overhead if you introduce iterator as a separate concept from the Node. The iterator could be a pair of the Node and the List this nodes  belongs to.. To delete an item  you call remove iterator and then  the check  and updating the size could be made there. But the Node itself will not contains extra data.. What I'm unclear is what is the exact data type for the Node I should be using. Should I use  Data.IORef?  What is the memory implication ?

Comment: Yes, using a "smart" iterator looks possible. `IORef` should be fine if you need mutability but not concurrency, and can live within the `IO` monad. It is the equivalent of a pointer, rougly put. `STRef s` is also an option, if `IO` is too restrictive.

Comment: What will be the memory footprint  of   (IORef a) if the size  of a is x ? Also  is there anything ready I can use ?

Comment: @GilShafriri best way to find out the footprint is write it yourself and test. :) doubly-linked lists are simple, it's not like it'd be thousands lines of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a first approximation, Haskell is a sufficiently expressive language that any algorithm implemented in another general purpose language can also be implemented in Haskell while preserving the asymptotic performance characteristics.  (This is a pretty low bar.  Most general-purpose languages are this expressive.)

In particular, though Haskell most naturally supports immutable data structures, it has sufficient support for mutable data that mutable data structures and their algorithms can usually be fairly directly translated into Haskell code.  There may be some overhead (often substantial overhead), and mutable data structures may be significantly more awkward to use than their immutable cousins, but it's still possible.

As a practical matter, though, matching the *actual* (as opposed to asymptotic) performance of a C++ implementation of a mutable data structure is likely to prove extremely difficult if not impossible.  It may be reasonable to get within 2-3 times the performance of C++, and getting within 5-10 times is pretty easy (see below).  However, if you need to match C++ performance, you would be probably better off writing the high performance mutating code in C++ and using the FFI (foreign function interface) to interface to that code.

Anyway, a "moderate performance" doubly linked-list with O(1) `length` is certainly possible, and there's no fundamental difficulty with maintaining mutable list-wide metadata.  The reason that `stm-linkedlist` does not provide an O(1) `length` is probably the same reason that C++ guaranteed only O(n) `std::list<>::size` performance [before C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size).  Namely, many practical uses of doubly-linked lists don't ever need to call `length`/`size`, and providing O(1) performance comes with an additional bookkeeping cost.

As a proof of concept, the following data types are sufficient to implement a fully mutable doubly-linked list with an O(1) length function.  Here, types and identifiers ending in underscores are for internal use only.  The list is strict in its pointers (so no infinite lists!) but lazy in its values.

```
data List a = List
  { headNode_ :: !(IORef (Node_ a))
  , length_ :: !(IORef Int) }
data Node_ a = Node_
  { prev_ :: !(IORef (Node_ a))
  , next_ :: !(IORef (Node_ a))
  , value_ :: a }
```

The `List` type contains a pointer (i.e., `IORef`) to an incomplete `headNode` that points to the start and end of the list (or to itself for an empty list) but has an undefined value field.  That makes this an unsafe node value, so it should never be directly accessible to the end-user.  The `List` also contains a pointer to the list length value.

An additional type `Node` (no underscore) is used to decorate a node pointer with its corresponding list (like the "iterator" from the comments), to make the list metadata available to functions that need it:

```
data Node a = Node
  { node_ :: !(IORef (Node_ a))
  , list_ :: !(List a) }
```

Note that `List` and `Node` are the user-facing data types for working with lists.

You create an `empty` list like so:

```
empty :: IO (List a)
empty = mdo
  n <- newIORef (Node_ n n undefined)
  List n <$> newIORef 0
```

Insertion before and after a given node works as follows.  Here's where the unsafe head node representation pays off, since the algorithm can treat insertion at the beginning and end of the list as special cases of insertion between the head node and an actual list node.

```
insertBefore :: a -> Node a -> IO (Node a)
insertBefore x Node{node_=rnode2, list_} = do
  Node_{prev_=rnode1} <- readIORef rnode2
  insertBetween_ x list_ rnode1 rnode2

insertAfter :: a -> Node a -> IO (Node a)
insertAfter x Node{node_=rnode1, list_} = do
  Node_{next_=rnode2} <- readIORef rnode1
  insertBetween_ x list_ rnode1 rnode2

insertBetween_ :: a -> List a -> IORef (Node_ a) -> IORef (Node_ a) -> IO (Node a)
insertBetween_ x l rnode1 rnode2 = do
  modifyIORef' (length_ l) succ
  newnode <- newIORef (Node_ rnode1 rnode2 x)
  modifyIORef' rnode1 (\n -> n{next_=newnode})
  modifyIORef' rnode2 (\n -> n{prev_=newnode})
  return $ Node newnode l
```

Since a user isn't allowed to "have" a head node, we need additional user-facing functions to insert at the beginning and end of a list:

```
prepend :: a -> List a -> IO (Node a)
prepend x l = insertAfter x (Node (headNode_ l) l)

append :: a -> List a -> IO (Node a)
append x l = insertBefore x (Node (headNode_ l) l)
```

Observe that all insertions go through `insertBetween_` which is responsible for increasing the length value.

Deletion is straightforward and uniform whether it's an internal node or one at the start or end.  All deletions go through this `delete` function which is responsible for decreasing the length value.

```
delete :: Node a -> IO ()
delete Node{node_,list_} = do
  modifyIORef' (length_ list_) pred
  Node_{next_, prev_} <- readIORef node_
  modifyIORef' prev_ (\n -> n{next_=next_})
  modifyIORef' next_ (\n -> n{prev_=prev_})
```

Deletion of the head node would be a disaster, but users aren't allowed to have such a `Node`, so we're safe.

If a user has a `Node`, she can move back and forth through the list:

```
prev :: Node a -> IO (Maybe (Node a))
prev Node{node_, list_} = do
  Node_{prev_} <- readIORef node_
  return $ maybeNode_ prev_ list_

next :: Node a -> IO (Maybe (Node a))
next Node{node_, list_} = do
  Node_{next_} <- readIORef node_
  return $ maybeNode_ next_ list_

maybeNode_ :: IORef (Node_ a) -> List a -> Maybe (Node a)
maybeNode_ n l =
  if n == headNode_ l
  then Nothing
  else Just (Node n l)
```

Note that we must take care never to give the user the head node, so `maybeNode_` here checks for it and returns `Nothing` instead.

To get started, the user can get the start or end of a `List` using the following functions (which use `prev` or `next` on the forbidden head node):

```
start :: List a -> IO (Maybe (Node a))
start l = next $ Node (headNode_ l) l

end :: List a -> IO (Maybe (Node a))
end l = prev $ Node (headNode_ l) l
```

All that's missing are a few miscellaneous query functions:

```
value :: Node a -> IO a
value = fmap value_ . readIORef . node_

null :: List a -> IO Bool
null l = (==0) <$> length l

length :: List a -> IO Int
length = readIORef . length_
```

some utilities to convert to plain lists:

```
toList :: List a -> IO [a]
toList = toList_ next_

toListRev :: List a -> IO [a]
toListRev = toList_ prev_

toList_ :: (Node_ a -> IORef (Node_ a)) -> List a -> IO [a]
toList_ dir l = go =<< readIORef h
  where h = headNode_ l
        go n = do
          if dir n == h then return []
            else do
            n' <- readIORef (dir n)
            (value_ n':) <$> go n'
```

and a `Show` instance for debugging:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
  showsPrec d lst = showParen (d > 10) $ showString "fromList " . showsPrec 11 (unsafePerformIO $ toList lst)
```

**WARNING:** This `Show` instance is unsafe if the list is mutated before the generated string is fully evaluated, so it should only be used for debugging (and probably removed from a production version).

Also, while it's not strictly necessary since we can delete and re-insert, no self-respecting mutable structure would be complete without in-place modification of elements:

```
modify :: (a -> a) -> Node a -> IO ()
modify f Node{node_} = modifyIORef' node_ (\n -> n { value_ = f (value_ n) })
```

Here's the full code.  (See the definition `ex1` for example usage.)  You're welcome to use it as a starting point for your own implementation.  It's untested and unbenchmarked, except that a couple of quick tests show that it's probably about 5-10x slower than a C++ implementation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns, RecursiveDo #-}

module LinkedList
  ( List, Node
  , value, null, length
  , empty, prepend, append, insertBefore, insertAfter, delete, modify
  , prev, next, start, end
  , toList, toListRev
  ) where

import System.IO.Unsafe
import Control.Monad
import Prelude hiding (null, length)

import Data.IORef

data List a = List
  { headNode_ :: !(IORef (Node_ a))
  , length_ :: !(IORef Int) }
data Node a = Node
  { node_ :: !(IORef (Node_ a))
  , list_ :: !(List a) }
data Node_ a = Node_
  { prev_ :: !(IORef (Node_ a))
  , next_ :: !(IORef (Node_ a))
  , value_ :: a }

-- unsafe show instance: remove from production version
instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
  showsPrec d lst = showParen (d > 10) $ showString "fromList " . showsPrec 11 (unsafePerformIO $ toList lst)

value :: Node a -> IO a
value = fmap value_ . readIORef . node_

null :: List a -> IO Bool
null l = (==0) <$> length l

length :: List a -> IO Int
length = readIORef . length_

empty :: IO (List a)
empty = mdo
  n <- newIORef (Node_ n n undefined)
  List n <$> newIORef 0

prepend :: a -> List a -> IO (Node a)
prepend x l = insertAfter x (Node (headNode_ l) l)

append :: a -> List a -> IO (Node a)
append x l = insertBefore x (Node (headNode_ l) l)

insertBefore :: a -> Node a -> IO (Node a)
insertBefore x Node{node_=rnode2, list_} = do
  Node_{prev_=rnode1} <- readIORef rnode2
  insertBetween_ x list_ rnode1 rnode2

insertAfter :: a -> Node a -> IO (Node a)
insertAfter x Node{node_=rnode1, list_} = do
  Node_{next_=rnode2} <- readIORef rnode1
  insertBetween_ x list_ rnode1 rnode2

insertBetween_ :: a -> List a -> IORef (Node_ a) -> IORef (Node_ a) -> IO (Node a)
insertBetween_ x l rnode1 rnode2 = do
  modifyIORef' (length_ l) succ
  newnode <- newIORef (Node_ rnode1 rnode2 x)
  modifyIORef' rnode1 (\n -> n{next_=newnode})
  modifyIORef' rnode2 (\n -> n{prev_=newnode})
  return $ Node newnode l

delete :: Node a -> IO ()
delete Node{node_,list_} = do
  modifyIORef' (length_ list_) pred
  Node_{next_, prev_} <- readIORef node_
  modifyIORef' prev_ (\n -> n{next_=next_})
  modifyIORef' next_ (\n -> n{prev_=prev_})

modify :: (a -> a) -> Node a -> IO ()
modify f Node{node_} = modifyIORef' node_ (\n -> n { value_ = f (value_ n) })

prev :: Node a -> IO (Maybe (Node a))
prev Node{node_, list_} = do
  Node_{prev_} <- readIORef node_
  return $ maybeNode_ prev_ list_

next :: Node a -> IO (Maybe (Node a))
next Node{node_, list_} = do
  Node_{next_} <- readIORef node_
  return $ maybeNode_ next_ list_

maybeNode_ :: IORef (Node_ a) -> List a -> Maybe (Node a)
maybeNode_ n l =
  if n == headNode_ l
  then Nothing
  else Just (Node n l)

start :: List a -> IO (Maybe (Node a))
start l = next $ Node (headNode_ l) l

end :: List a -> IO (Maybe (Node a))
end l = prev $ Node (headNode_ l) l

toList :: List a -> IO [a]
toList = toList_ next_

toListRev :: List a -> IO [a]
toListRev = toList_ prev_

toList_ :: (Node_ a -> IORef (Node_ a)) -> List a -> IO [a]
toList_ dir l = go =<< readIORef h
  where h = headNode_ l
        go n = do
          if dir n == h then return []
            else do
            n' <- readIORef (dir n)
            (value_ n':) <$> go n'

ex1 :: IO (List Int)
ex1 = do
  t <- empty
  mapM_ (flip prepend t) [10,9..1]
  mapM_ (flip append t) [11..20]
  return t
```

Comment: could you offer a few hints as to why the `unsafePerformIO . toList` is safe to use here? or if there are some preconditions for the user code to follow, for it, then what are they?

Comment: Ha!  Yes, it's totally unsafe and should be used for debugging only.   You can demonstrate it's unsafe with a program like:  `main = do { t <- ex1; let { s = show t }; print (head s); Just e <- start t; modify (+1) e; print s }`.  I've added a warning to the answer, since this is an important point.

Comment: Many thanks! I  wonder why this kind of mutable linked list code is not part of the Haskell standard libraries. It is fair to say that Haskell community did not invest  yet in mutable standard libraries   ?

Comment: maybe add a clarification to the answer as to what "unsafe" means -- is it going to print the modified contents instead of the original one, or cause a segfault (if e.g. the head node was deleted)? (I didn't test this myself)